# This insert query in webforms is throwing an error and I'm not sure why

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, webforms

It's a web forms application and I'm having some trouble finding out what exactly it is going wrong.

I am trying to insert info into the `logins` table.

Everything works apart from when I add `[User]` which is the username of the person logged in at the time. there is another entry for username but that's working fine.

[Image Of The Logins Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B66La.png)

The Aspx.cs code behind:

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
        string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;

        int webid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlWebsite.SelectedItem.Value);
        string username = username.Text;
        string _email = email.Text;
        string pass = password.Text;
        string Ainfo = info.Text;
        string loguser = User.Identity.Name;

        //string connectionstring = "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebProg-20170720092452.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebProg-20170720092452;Integrated Security=true";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());

        string query = "Insert into Logins(WebsiteID, Username, Password, AdditionalInfo, User, Email) Values ( @webid, @username, @pass, @Ainfo, @loguser, @_email)";

        SqlCommand insertQuery = new SqlCommand(query,connection);

        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webid", webid);
        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ainfo", Ainfo);
        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loguser", User.Identity.Name);  
        insertQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_email", _email);

        connection.Open();
        insertQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

The ASPX markup:

Add A Login

```
    <div id="websiteDetails" class="col-md-4">

        <label id="Label1" for="websiteName">
            Website Name:               

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [WebsiteList]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWebsite" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="AddAWebsite" />
        </label>
        <label id="Label3" for="username">
            Username/Email:
            <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
        <label id="Label4" for="password">
            Password:
            <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
        <label id="Label6" for="email">
            Email Address:
            <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
        <label id="Label5" for="info">
            Additional Info:
            <asp:TextBox ID="info" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <div id="loginDetails" class="col-md-4">
        <p>Website not showing up in the list? Add a Website to the list.</p>
        <label id="Label7" for="websiteName">
            Website Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="Wname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
        <label id="Label8" for="link">
            Website Address:
            <asp:TextBox ID="link" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </label>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="AddWebsite" runat="server" Text="Add Website" OnClick="AddWebsite_Click" />



</div>
<asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" Text="Add Login" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="add_Click" />
```

[This is the error message that doesn't tell me much at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2itC.png)

Comment: What are the types of the columns in database?

Comment: What are the values of the variables you add as parameters?

Comment: the error actually is exceptionally clear as to whats wrong.  See Rahul's answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `User` is a reserved word and that's the issue here as can be seen in your posted `INSERT` statement. It needs to be escaped like `[User]` if it's SQL Server or use ANSI style escaping using double quotes `"User"`

```
Insert into Logins(WebsiteID, Username, Password, AdditionalInfo, [User], Email)
```

Comment: @Seangol1, then consider accepting the answer by clicking the check button